# Placing JSON data(temperature) without long, lat in OpenLayers

Tags: raster, openlayers, query

I executed the WCPS query for fetching the raster temperature data in JSON format using the following query:

```
for $c in (temperature_new) return encode($c[Lat(50:70), Long(30: 60), ansi("2022-11-24T00:00:00.000Z"), plev(11050)],"json")
```

As a result, I got a JSON file with only temperature in a format shown below,

```
[[t1,t2,t3...],[t1,t2,t3...],[t1,t2,t3,...]]
```

but there were no longitude and latitude. Would it be possible to add this scalar data as a layer of the map using OpenLayers?

Comment: How many entries in the outer array and each component array?  It is likely to be rows and columns within the requested extent.